# Returning values from three tables in different lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

Table_1 - Main, where Global_ID is the primary key used in all tables.

| Global_ID |
| --- |
| 001 |

Table_2 - Using Global_ID to query for F_ID values

| Global_ID | F_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 |
| 001 | 222222 |
| 001 | 33333 |

Table_3 - Using Global_ID to query for F_ID values

| Global_ID | F_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 444444 |

So, I need to do a query that returns The Global_ID and the values that are both equal and different in Table_2 and Table_3.

- If Table_2 and Table_3 have the same values, they need to be show in the same line.
- If Table_2 and Table_3 have different values, they need to be show in a new line
  Like this:

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | - |
| 001 | 222222 | - |
| 001 | 33333 | - |
| 001 | - | 444444 |

The way I am doing (case) is returning like this

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | - |
| 001 | 222222 | - |
| 001 | 33333 | - |

This return is due to this query that I have poorly done

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT T1.*    "Global_ID",
   ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,T2.F_ID),'-')    "T2_F_ID",
   CASE WHEN T2.F_ID IS NULL AND T3.F_ID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,T3.F_ID)
        WHEN T2.F_ID IS NULL AND T3.F_ID IS NULL THEN '-'
        WHEN T2.F_ID = T3.F_ID THEN T3.F_ID
        WHEN T2.F_ID <> T3.F_ID THEN '-'
   END    "T3_F_ID"
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.Global_ID = T1.Global_ID
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.GLOBAL_ID = T1.Global_ID
```

This way I know there is some logic issues and that if Table_2 returns even 1 value, the values that are not the same in Table_3 will not be returned but I can't find out what to do and I am stuck...

Some other returns that might happen:

- When there might be the same F_ID in Table_2 and Table_3, but also when the F_ID is not fouind in one of the tables.

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | 1111 |
| 001 | 222222 | - |
| 001 | 33333 | - |
| 001 | - | 444444 |

- When there are no F_ID in Table_2 and only in Table_3

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | - | 444444 |

- When there are not the same F_ID in Table_3 and only in Table_2

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | - |
| 001 | 222222 | - |
| 001 | 33333 | - |

- When there are no values in Table_2 and Table_3

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | - | - |

- When all values in Table_2 were found in Table_3

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | 1111 |
| 001 | 222222 | 222222 |
| 001 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 001 | 444444 | 444444 |

Another example with more Global_IDs:

| Global ID | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | 1111 |
| 001 | 222222 | - |
| 001 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 001 | 444444 | 444444 |
| 002 | 1234 | - |
| 002 | 5678 | 5678 |
| 003 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 003 | 1212 | 1212 |
| 003 | - | 1111 |
| 004 | - | - |
| 005 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 005 | 444444 | 444444 |
| 005 | - | 1111 |
| 005 | - | 222222 |
| 005 | - | 33333 |

Please help.

Comment: I don't understand how you get your results "When there are mixed returns for Table_2 and Table_3" or rather I don't understand what your sample data would be.

Comment: I suspect you want a union to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: "When there are mixed returns for Table_2 and Table_3" is when the same F_ID might by found in both Tables 2 and 3

Comment: @danillofrg please enhance your sample data to show that.

Comment: Also, being a rookie like I am, I don't know if UNION would not work because I have at least 15 different fields that I need to return in Table_1 that are not present in table_2 (2 fields returned) and in table 3 (6 fields returned). 
The common information between all three tables is the Global_ID and the common return that I need between Table_2 and Table_3, appart form Global_ID, is the F_ID. I will edit the post in a few minutes to give more data.

Comment: @danillofrg just don't fundamentally change the question now that you have an answer. If what you are asking is quite different you may need a new question.

Comment: @DaleK No it's the same problem... I just might phrased it badly. I added more examples

Comment: Sounds like a simple full outer join to me.

Comment: @TN do show - I thought that too, but couldn't get it working in the short time I had.

Comment: @DaleK - Maybe a step above simple after pulling in the third table, but it does the job. (The grouped joins is something I only rarely use. Typically I've used it to perform left join via a junction table, when the distant table needed additional conditions applied.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `union` 2 queries together to obtain the results you want.

```
create table Table_1 (Global_ID int);
create table Table_2 (Global_ID int, F_ID int);
create table Table_3 (Global_ID int, F_ID int);

insert into Table_1 (Global_ID) values (1);
insert into Table_2 (Global_ID, F_ID) values (1,1111),(1,22222), (1,33333);
insert into Table_3 (Global_ID, F_ID) values (1,1111),(1,44444);

select t1.Global_Id, t2.F_ID T2_F_ID, t3.F_ID T3_F_ID
from Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2 on t2.Global_ID = t1.Global_ID
left join Table_3 t3 on t3.Global_ID = t1.Global_ID and t2.F_ID = t3.F_ID

union all
  
select t1.Global_Id, null, t3.F_ID
from Table_1 t1
inner join Table_3 t3 on t3.Global_ID = t1.Global_ID
-- Exclude because already handled in the first part of the union
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Table_2 t2
  where t2.Global_ID = t1.Global_ID
  and t2.F_ID = t3.F_ID
)
```

Returns:

| Global_Id | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 1111 |
| 1 | 22222 | null |
| 1 | 33333 | null |
| 1 | null | 44444 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hc-spuqu)

Note: Providing the DDL+DML as shown here makes it much easier to assist.

Comment: I see what you did here and will will try it

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks a lot @DaleK 
I had some problems because all three tables are sub-queries and the amount of fields confused me  but in the end it all worked using your solution

THANKS!

Comment: No worries, do also take a look at the other solution as it might be cleaner and more scalable, if slightly harder to understand.

Comment: I will save it to try tomorrow morning (10pm here and I am done for today). Since the end solution, if all data validated, will go to a BI report, the most elegant and fast one will be the one. So I will try it for sure

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to join the two data tables (Table_2 and Table_3). That join (grouped using parentheses) is then joined back with the ID table (Table_1).

Note the the parentheses after the `LEFT JOIN` causes the outer join between the Table_2 and Table_3 to be evaluated first. This is not a subselect.

```
SELECT T1.Global_Id, T2.F_ID AS T2_F_ID, T3.F_ID AS T3_F_ID
FROM Table_1 T1
LEFT JOIN (
    Table_2 T2
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table_3 T3
        ON T3.Global_ID = T2.Global_ID
        AND T3.F_ID = T2.F_ID
)
    ON COALESCE(T2.Global_ID, T3.Global_ID) = T1.Global_ID
ORDER BY
    T1.Global_Id,
    COALESCE(T2.F_ID, T3.F_ID)
```

The problem with the above is that it doesn't properly handle duplicate values such as those that are present for Global_ID = 005. To handle duplicates, we need to assign distinct row values and add that to our logic. This can be done with some Common Table Expressions (CTEs) and a ROW_NUMBER() window function.

```
;WITH Table_2N AS (
     SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Global_ID, F_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum
     FROM Table_2
),
Table_3N AS (
     SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Global_ID, F_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum
     FROM Table_3
)
SELECT T1.Global_Id, T2.F_ID AS T2_F_ID, T3.F_ID AS T3_F_ID
FROM Table_1 T1
LEFT JOIN (
    Table_2N T2
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table_3N T3
        ON T3.Global_ID = T2.Global_ID
        AND T3.F_ID = T2.F_ID
        AND T3.RowNum = T2.RowNum
)
    ON COALESCE(T2.Global_ID, T3.Global_ID) = T1.Global_ID
ORDER BY
    T1.Global_Id,
    COALESCE(T2.F_ID, T3.F_ID),
    COALESCE(T2.RowNum, T3.RowNum)
```

The `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is just a don't care placeholder to satisfy the required syntax.

Results:

| Global_Id | T2_F_ID | T3_F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1111 | 1111 |
| 001 | 222222 | null |
| 001 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 001 | 444444 | 444444 |
| 002 | 1234 | null |
| 002 | 5678 | 5678 |
| 003 | null | 1111 |
| 003 | 1212 | 1212 |
| 003 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 004 | null | null |
| 005 | null | 1111 |
| 005 | null | 222222 |
| 005 | 33333 | 33333 |
| 005 | null | 33333 |
| 005 | 444444 | 444444 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M7SktJmC).

It is worth noting that the table joins could also be rearranged and rewritten as:

```
FROM Table_2N T2
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_3N T3
    ON T3.Global_ID = T2.Global_ID
    AND T3.F_ID = T2.F_ID
    AND T3.RowNum = T2.RowNum
RIGHT JOIN Table_1 T1
    ON T1.Global_ID = COALESCE(T2.Global_ID, T3.Global_ID)
```

The results are identical. Which is more readable and best conveys intent is subjective.